# ng-Pattern in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

Users enter username here and username is just number

```
<fieldset class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"
                   class="text-warning"
                   ng-class="{'text-left': form.userName.$valid}"
                   autocomplete="off"                  
                   ng-model="self.user.userName"
                   name="userName"
                   ng-required="true"
                   ng-blur="self.user.usernamePlaceholder = false"
                   ng-focus="self.user.usernamePlaceholder = true"
                   maxlength="20"
                   onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) { this.removeAttribute('readonly');this.blur(); this.focus() }" />
        </fieldset>
```

But ng-pattern dosent work

I can type anything

Comment: It does not apply pattern on user inputs but on form submit validation. Hence, use can input anything.

Answer (score 0):

When we use `ng-pattern` in fact we set input validation for that input.

**for example:**

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-model="test" />
{{test}}
```

> This input already validate by `ng-pattern` that mean when i want to
>   type **test123** return **empty** to me and when type **123** will
>   return **123**, so your codes is fine.

But what you want is not **pattern** it's **directive**, i write custom directive `ngInteger`:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", [])

app.directive('ngInteger', function(){
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
       modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
           // this next if is necessary for when using ng-required on your input. 
           // In such cases, when a letter is typed first, this parser will be called
           // again, and the 2nd time, the value will be undefined
           if (inputValue == undefined) return '' 
           var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
           if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
              modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
              modelCtrl.$render();
           }         

           return transformedInput;         
       });
     }
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">

<form name="form">
  <h3>ng-pattern</h3>
  <input type="text" name="pattern" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-model="test1" /> {{test1}}
  <p>test 1 validation: {{form.pattern.$valid}}</p>
  <h3>ng-integer</h3>
  <input type="text" name="integer" ng-integer ng-model="test2" /> {{test2}}
  <p>test 2 validation: {{form.integer.$valid}}</p>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary to use `ng-pattern`,if you are using directive.
It actually does the same thing on `keypress` itself.

```
valid-number here is directive mentioned below. Mention the `maxlength` if needed.
```

**In HTML:**

```
<input type="text" valid-number maxlength="12" ng-model="test" />
```

Use this **directive** in `input` tag

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.directive('validNumber', function() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if(!ngModelCtrl) {
                return; 
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
                if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
                    var val = '';
                }
                var clean = val.replace( /[^0-9]+/g, '');
                if (val !== clean) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return clean;
            });

            element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
                if(event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Hope this helps..